# maven assembly create jar with dependency and class path

Tags: java, maven, classpath, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven project with a lot of dependencies.
I want to pack all in a jar with dependency using assembly plugin, but I don't won't all the dependencies jars unpacked in a big mess.  I want all of them do go into lib folder, but I don't know how to add the class path.
my pom:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-weather</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>simple-weather</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

                     <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>adi.com.weather.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>package.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

my assembly file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
    <id>test5</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>

        </fileSet>

    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Looks like you have the correct pom entries. Where is the problem?  The jars not going into lib folder?  Manifest having incorrect path of jars?

Comment: the classPath in the manifest didn't work good, but i found a soulution

Comment: Nice work Adi Mor. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Comment: Adir Mor, what is the solution?

Comment: @Adi Mor 
I am also facing similar problem. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

He was probably reconfiguring his maven dependency plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${distDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now, when your run `mvn package`, all your dependency jars will go to `target/lib` (or whatever your distDirectory is).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If maven-jar-plugin is not generating the entry Class-Path in the manifest file although you have set `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>`, make sure you are using version 2.2 or newer of the plugin.

It seems that the bug [MJAR-83](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-83) in version 2.1 was preventing the plugin from listing the dependencies in Class-Path.